# Force image to a specific size if it is larger without distorting the image?

Tags: html, image

I'm currently using an image and displaying it in 100px by 100px. Unfortunately, some of the images are distorted...

How can I display them in 100 x 100 even if there original size is 450 x 450?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the entire image, setting the size to 100 x 100 is going to distort the image as you know.

If you're not so bothered about displaying the entire image you can set the image as a background instead and display a portion of the image in your thumbnail.

To do this you can use something like the following:

**HTML**

```
<div class="thumbnail firstImage">
   <a href="[link to full size image]">Thumbnail of some image</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.thumbnail{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
.thumbnail a{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

.firstImage a{
  background: url([path to full size image]) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```